# Multiple applications under one domain website best architecture

Tags: php, architecture, laravel

I am developing an internal website which consists of around 30 individual utilities (and more will be added in the future). I am trying to do this with Laravel. What would be the best practice to do this?

Here are some characteristics of this website.

- Some utilities are big enough to be considered as individual applications
- Some are very small, displaying static data without user interaction, but with database interaction
- Some display dynamic contents as a result of interaction with users
- Some are CRUD utilities
- Each utility has its own permission, and each user has different sets of permissions
- With one login, the user should be able to access utilities that he/she is permitted to use
- Each utility interacts with different tables in different databases.They have some tables being used in common, but that is rare case

Currently, I have separate controller, model, view for each utility, which makes MVC pattern useless.I thought of making each utility as a bundle, but then it violates DRYness(I probably have to repeat some parts of my code).

What is the best way to construct this website?

Comment: I would ask a few more questions, do the applications need to interact with each other? Are they going to be developed by the same team or split between teams? What is your release process like?

Comment: Do [agile development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) with your team.

Comment: @datasage answers for your questions. 1. There is no interaction between each application. 2. It will be developed by myself. I am the only web guy here. 3. I am not sure what you meant by release process. We have these utilities already running on the server, but very poorly structured by me a year ago. Since more applications will be added in the near future, I want to make it more scalable. So, there is no hurry if that is what you meant.

Comment: WIth release process I am referring to the process of making changes and pushing them into production. With only 1 person its probably not very involved. I'll put some ideas down in an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting everything into one single monolithic application may be fine for the time being, but it could present some challenges in the future. This has to do with being able to release individual applications separately.

If I design what you have from scratch, I would be looking at something like this:

1. Base framework, probably extended of an existing framework with components added that will be common to all the applications. This framework should be versioned by itself and would be linked to each application (Using something like an svn external). Each application could choose which framework version they were using in case a change presents a break to one or more applications.
2. Single signon, If you have an existing LDAP server, domain controller, google apps, I would use that for basic authentication to any of the applications.
3. All applications could access the same database or data stores.
4. You may be able to centralize permissions control but it depends. This could get rather unwieldy but at the same time it would give you one place to handle permissions. Maybe allow each app to publish the permissions that it needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you be more specific on #3? Maybe having one database config file that all applications refer to? Also, I understand the #2 and #4, but I am little confused with #1. Correct me if I got it wrong. There is one base framework with common components of each application added. Each application uses this copy of base framework. Because base framework will be modified in the future, keep track of versions of framework that each application is compatible with.

Comment: On 3, you could have a shared file, or each application has its own. I suppose it depends how the framework works and what variations each application might need. On 1 each application will use a version of the base framework, if you use a process of taging it may not always be the same version. Lets say application A uses version 1.2 of the base framework, while application B uses 1.1. At a later point, you can update application B to use 1.2, if you control that on an application level, you can limit breaking changes until you have time to fix them.

Comment: Okay, I think I understood. I would need some time to structure this based on your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've been using git for a while, so I was thinking I could use git tag to keep track of framework version. Then it occurred to me that, if I want to update all applications' framework version, I would have to do `git pull` command for 30 times. Am I thinking something wrong here?

Comment: You would probably use a git submodule, this works similar to an svn external.